# System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, sfml

I want to write the game in C #.

I use the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using SFML.Graphics;
using SFML.System;
using SFML.Window;
namespace opengl
{
static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {

        RenderWindow app = new RenderWindow(VideoMode.DesktopMode,"Game");

        app.SetFramerateLimit(60);

        while (app.IsOpen)
        {
            app.Clear();
            drawQuad(app, Color.Green, 500, 500, 200, 500, 300, 100);
            app.Display();
        }
    }

    static void drawQuad(RenderWindow w ,Color c,int x1,int y1,int w1,int x2,int y2,int w2)
    {
        ConvexShape shape = new ConvexShape(4);
        shape.FillColor = c;
        shape.SetPoint(0, new Vector2f(x1 - w1, y1));
        shape.SetPoint(1, new Vector2f(x2 - w2, y2));
        shape.SetPoint(2, new Vector2f(x1 + w1, y1));
        shape.SetPoint(3, new Vector2f(x2 + w2, y2));
        w.Draw(shape);
    }
}
}
```

But I am faced with the following error.

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'sfmlnet-window-2, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

Comment: You are likely mixing 32 and 64 bit assemblies, check if "sfmlnet-window-2" is the same architecture as the application calling it

Comment: No, all are 64 bits.

Comment: What about any dependant assemblies?  Not the ones you directly use, but those referenced by them.  There must be some 32-bit assembly referenced somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved.
I should not use the 64-bit version, I should use the 32-bit version.